# Is there any canon information about what happened to K'mtar?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In ["Firstborn"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Firstborn_(episode)), the 21st episode of the 7th season of *Star Trek: The Next Generation*, we learn that K'mtar is actually [someone else](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Alexander_Rozhenko).

The ending of the episode leaves it ambiguous as to what happens to him.

From the [episode](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/273.htm):

> (Alexander is practicing with his bat'leth)
>
> ALEXANDER: I've been  waiting. Where's K'mtar?
>
> WORF: He had to leave. He was called away.
>
> ALEXANDER: He never said goodbye.

This [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89271/why-didnt-the-enterprise-disappear-in-the-star-trek-movie-first-contact-when-th) suggests that the fake K'mtar went back to his own time, nothing in the episode suggests that this is what happened (other mistakes are made as well, such as Worf's suggestion that K'mtar would find Worf alive in his own time).

I always assumed he went to live out his life as K'mtar.

**Is there any information what happened to K'mtar?**

Comment: He can't have lived out his life *as K'Mtar* because he was impersonating him.

Comment: @Valorum - While this is true, I didn't think it all the way through and thought he went off to do other things, not necessarily back to the homeworld.

Comment: Given the way Star Trek handles timelines, I always assumed he simply faded away after saying goodbye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [original screenplay](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/273.txt) the ending plays out slightly differently. Worf tells K'Mtar **to return to his own timeline and pursue the cause of peace**. K'Mtar agrees, they hug and that's the scene.

> **WORF:** *The cause of peace is a worthy one... go back, and continue to work for it. Your struggle must continue.*
>
> **K'MTAR:** *But it is a futile struggle...*
>
> **WORF:** *No... you've already changed things more than you realize.*

What's not immediately clear is whether Alexander has risked impersonating a real Klingon that he knows is close to his family but that his father has never met, or whether he's used time travel shenanigans to inveigle himself into the House of Mogh by traveling back and forth in order to set up his fake identity.

Comment: *What's not immediately clear is whether Alexander has risked impersonating a real Klingon that he knows is close to his family but that his father has never met*. I wondered this myself, because Worf describes K'mtar as *"An advisor so trusted that he is made part of a family."*. At some point Worf would have met him.

Comment: @SvetlanaofVodianova - I'm assuming Alexander would have intimate knowledge of his father's affairs. He presumably could have chosen someone that his father had *mentioned* that he'd never met. It's still a bit of a risk though, assuming that Worf doesn't have a photo album in his quarters.